# muxing stream encoding on h264 (interlace) with ffmpeg to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

mux stream to mp4 container：
when i mux the stream(720p) with ffmpeg to mp4,it works ok. BUT when i mux the stream(1080i) with ffmpeg to mp4,the output file can not play normaly in VLC.the generat file have many Snow points.
Do I have any arguments that are not set right? 
Is there any need for special settings of the parameters?
Waiting for your answer! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to reply, this problem very early settlement of the method is to split the two interlace data in a frame, respectively into ffmpeg, multiplexing such is correct, at least for now playing does not appear snowflakes phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ffmbc](https://github.com/bcoudurier/FFmbc) instead, if you need to mux the interlaced stream into a MP4 container without re-encoding. Recommended due to a quirk of how ffmpeg MP4 muxer works with interlaced streams. See [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17194/1871) for details.

If you're ok with re-encoding, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf 18 -vf yadif -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Adjust the CRF value for quality/size tradeoff. Lower values provide better quality at expense of file size.

Comment: I have read the article you gived，But they are too complicated, I can't understand.what I got from the link is that the ffmpeg has a bug ,can not mux interlaced stream into a mp4 container without re-encoding.Is it right?If there are other ways, what should I do?Looking forward to your suggestions！